# Dynamic query generation using bash

Tags: bash

```
select * from table1 where condition1 = $condition1 and condition2 = $condition2;
select * from table2 where condition3 = $condition3 and condition4 = $condition4;
parameter:{ condition1 = "value1",
            condition2 = "value2",
            condition3 = "value3",
            condition4 = "value4"}
```

Expected output :

```
select * from table1 where condition1 = "value1" and condition2 = "value2";
select * from table2 where condition3 = "value3" and condition4 = "value4";
```

Queries are stored in one file and parameters are stored in other file. 
The number and name of the condition can be of any number. 
How to achieve the output using bash commands ?

Comment: Seems formatting is not complete yet.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor to make that code more readable, please.

Comment: you are definitely missing this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please don't construct SQL queries in `bash`! Use a language/environment/library that will properly quote and escape your parameters for SQL.

Comment: I  had done the same using spark, I want to achieve the same using bash,